# .tpl file and %%. Twig engine template

Tags: twig

I get .tpl file which has %% variables in it.

Example:

```
%%GLOBAL_Error%%
```

Is this twig template engine? I want to check if variable is not empty but i can't do this with regular twig syntax.

```
{% if GLOBAL_Error is defined %}
```

How can I do this?

Link for twig...
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/if.html

Comment: What's the error that you get?

Comment: no error just i get output as text

Comment: You can convert your TPL/PHP in to Twig code here : https://www.easycodetools.com/tool/php-to-twig here, is online PHP to twig converter ( online TPL to twig converter )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't twig.
I suppose that is [smarty](http://www.smarty.net/)

By take a fast look to documentation, i suppose that `%` is use for escape the `%` itself, so `%%GLOBAL_Error%%`  will be `%GLOBAL_Error%`